# Stuck trying to create a Matlab GUI with radio button for multiple functions

Tags: matlab, button, user-interface

I have a problem when linking 2 radio buttons with a popup button in Matlab. This two radio buttons are created in order to "call" the popup button to change the color of two different plots (Plot selected, esp or pdf). I have tried many things so far, but nothing works. I hope you can help me in finding the solution.

Thank you in advance.

```
function First_Model ()
figure_color=[0.89 0.99 0.99];
panel_color=[1 1 1];


hFigure= figure('MenuBar','none',...
'Units','Pixels',...
'Color',figure_color,...
'Toolbar','none',...
'Name','First model',...
'resize','off',...
'NumberTitle','off',...
'Position',[1 810 1280 683]);

movegui(hFigure,'center');

warning off MATLAB:uitabgroup:OldVersion  % turn off warning

%---------------Tab group---------
hg=uitabgroup('Parent',hFigure,...
'units','pixels','position',...
[1.5 10 1277 677]);

%---------------Tabs---------
ht(1)=uitab(hg,'Title','Plot');

%---------------Main Panel---------
hPanelB = uipanel(...
'Title','',...
'Fontsize',22,...
'Parent', ht(1),...
'Units','Pixels',...
'BorderWidth',1,...
'Position',[1 1 1263 640],...
'BackgroundColor',panel_color);

%---------------Sub_Panels---------

hSubPanel1 = uipanel('Parent',ht(1),'Units',...
'pixels','Title','Press Run','Fontsize',17,...
'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],'Position',[5.5 194 595  133],...
'BorderWidth',2);

hSubPanel2 = uipanel('Parent',hPanelB,'Units',...
'pixels','Title','Plots','Fontsize',14,...
'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],'Position',[600 3 640 615],...
'BorderWidth',2);

 hSubPanel3 = uipanel('Parent',hSubPanel2,'Units',...
'pixels','Title','Adjustment','Fontsize',14,...
   'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1 ],'Position',[210 230 218 135],...
   'BorderWidth',1);

%------------- Plots ------

 hGraph1 = axes('Parent',hSubPanel2,'Units',...
'pixels','Position',[55 420 195 135],'Color',[1 1 1]);

 hGraph2 = axes('Parent',hSubPanel2,'Units',...
'pixels','Position',[415 420 195 135],'Color',[1 1 1]);

%--------Radio Buttons -----------------------------------------------------------------

 hRadio = uibuttongroup('visible','off','Position',[.05,.05,.9,.9],...
'Parent',hSubPanel3,'Units','Normalized');

 radio1 = uicontrol('Style','RadioButton','String',...
'F(t)','FontSize',10,'Position',[0.05,0.70,0.46,0.22],...
'Parent',hRadio,'Tag','esp','Units','normalized',...
'HandleVisibility','off');

 radio2 = uicontrol('Style','RadioButton','String','P(t)',...
'FontSize',10,'Position',[0.58,0.70,0.46,0.22],...
'Parent',hRadio,'Tag','pdf','Units','normalized',...
'HandleVisibility','off');

%--- Tuner frame-------------------

 hcolPopup = uicontrol('Parent',hSubPanel3,'Units',...
'normalized','BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],'FontSize',15,...
'ForegroundColor',[0 0 0],'Position',[0.08 0.33 0.48 0.12],...
'String',{  'Color'; 'Red'; 'Yellow'; 'Green'; 'Blue'; 'Magenta'; 'Black'; },...
'Style','popupmenu','Value',1,'Callback',@colPopup_Callback);

%----- Push Buttons---

 hMainPushButton = uicontrol('Parent',hSubPanel1,'Units',...
'normalized','Position',[0.32 0.42 0.32 0.38],'Style','Pushbutton',....
'String',' Run!','FontSize',25,'Callback',@MainPushButton_Callback);


 handle_list=...
 [hFigure,hg,ht(1),hSubPanel1,...
 hSubPanel2,hSubPanel3,hGraph1,...
 hGraph2,hRadio,radio1,radio2,hcolPopup,hMainPushButton];
 set(handle_list,'Units','normalized');

 set(hRadio,'Visible','on');

%--- EVALUATION FUNCTION BEGINS -------------------------------

 function MainPushButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata)

 x = 1:80;
 o = 1-poisscdf(x,65);
 p = 1-poisspdf(x,2);

 axes(hGraph1);
 plot(x,o,'Tag','esp');
 xlabel('Xlabel','FontName','Helvetica','FontSize', 18,'fontweight','bold')
 ylabel('F(t)','FontName','Helvetica','FontSize',18);grid on;set(gca,'FontSize',18)

 axes(hGraph2);
 plot(x,p,'Tag','pdf');xlabel('Number','FontName','Helvetica','FontSize', 18)
 ylabel('P(t)','FontName','Helvetica','FontSize',18);grid on;set(gca,'FontSize',18)

 end


 function colPopup_Callback(hObject, eventdata)
    colors=get(hcolPopup,'string');
    index=get(hcolPopup,'value');
    color=colors{index};
    switch color
        case 'Red'
            h=findobj(hGraph1,'Tag','esp');set(h,'color','r')
        case 'Blue'
            h=findobj(hGraph1,'Tag','esp');set(h,'color','b')
        case 'Yellow'
            h=findobj(hGraph1,'Tag','esp');set(h,'color','y')
        case 'Green'
            h=findobj(hGraph1,'Tag','pdf');set(h,'color','g') 
        case 'Magenta'
            h=findobj(hGraph1,'Tag','pdf');set(h,'color','m')
        case 'Black'
            h=findobj(hGraph1,'Tag','pdf');set(h,'color','k')

    end
end
```

end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you could have callbacks on the radio buttons/buttongroup that update some shared state variable, but assuming either plot is allowed to be any of the six colours it's even simpler to just check which button is selected at the point that it matters. Here's one way of doing that:

```
function colPopup_Callback(hObject, eventdata)
    colors = get(hcolPopup, 'String');
    index = get(hcolPopup, 'Value');
    color = colors{index};

    % since the radio buttons have the appropriate Tags set already
    tag = get(get(hRadio, 'SelectedObject'), 'Tag');

    h = findobj([hGraph1 hGraph2], 'Tag', tag);
    switch color
        case 'Red'
            set(h, 'Color', 'r');
        case 'Blue'
            set(h, 'Color', 'b');
        case 'Yellow'
            set(h, 'Color', 'y');
        case 'Green'
            set(h, 'Color', 'g');
        case 'Magenta'
            set(h, 'Color', 'm');
        case 'Black'
            set(h, 'Color', 'k');
    end
end
```

---

If, however, I've misinterpreted that and you want to *change* which colours are selectable based on which plot is selected, you would need to use the callback approach to update the popupmenu accordingly:

```
function hRadio_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject,eventdata)
   switch get(eventdata.NewValue,'Tag')
        case 'esp'
            choices= {'Color'; 'Red'; 'Blue'; 'Yellow'};
        case 'pdf'
            choices= {'Color'; 'Green'; 'Magenta'; 'Black'};
    end
    set(hcolPopup, 'Value', 1, 'String', choices);
end
```

and the original `colPopup_Callback` should suffice (albeit using `hGraph2` for the pdf plot).

Comment: Dear @Notlikethat,

the first part of your answer solved my problem. It does work PERFECT!! 

Thank you very much indeed!.

Héctor